# EXCEL TEXTJOIN with IF and UNIQUE IN O365

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Using Excel O365.
**My formula:** {=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(IF('Sheet1'!C$2:F$36=$B2,'Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$36,"")))}

**My 4 Objectives:**

1. When a cell in an array ('Sheet1'!C$2:F$36) equals a cell in my
   current row ($B2) returns the corresponding cell in ('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$36).
2. Separate all results with a comma and a space after the comma
3. Ignore Blank Cells.
4. Remove Duplicates.

**My Result:**
Objective 1, 2 and 3 works Perfectly. However, I cannot reduce to Unique values.
***Important note:*** If I change to look at a single column, change my lookup array to ('Sheet1'!C$2:**C**$36) then it works perfectly and returns only unique values.

How can I return unique values when lookup is an array?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A36,MMULT(--(C2:F36=B2),SEQUENCE(4,,,0)),"No Hits"))
```